# Keep getting logged out of StackOverflow today

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

Throughout the day today, I've been logged out of SO. Usually when I have closed my SO tab and open a new one, but not always. I haven't experienced this previously.

I would suspect OpenId, but I have experienced no issues with Meta.

Is this isolated to only me?

I'm using Chrome (4.1.249.1042 (42199))

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Got that as well! Only a couple of times though. And only on meta.

Comment: This question is long ago, but I have this problem today 3/1/2016

Comment: I have the same problem 7/18/2017

Comment: @sln its probably not the same issue. You should create a new post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I see what this is, and have fixed it.

NB: has nothing to do with OpenID, is completely a cookie issue.

Comment: @Jeff: +1. Sorry about the dupe, I guess I didn't look hard enough.  Couldn't see the forest for the trees... or whatever :-) Thanks for the fix.

Comment: Thank you. I had same issue yesterday and I thought its because of my browser. :-)

Comment: So if this is the accepted answer, what is the fix again? Delete cookies?

Answer (score 3):

My experience is that I was logged out, and cannot log back in on SO. No problem here.

Using FF3.6.2 or FF3.6

Answer (score 2):

I was going to say I'd had no problems with IE7, but just now the exact same thing happened to me.
I had opened a question and was curious about the vote count, so I clicked on it, got an error, scratched my head, and reloaded the page to find that I'd been logged out somehow.