# Keep getting logged out of Chrome dev

Tags: bug, status-declined, login, google-chrome

Over the last couple of weeks I have been experiencing the same problem as described in [Keep getting logged out of StackOverflow today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44469/keep-getting-logged-out-of-stackoverflow-today). As you can see from the screenshot of my openid activity I have to log in every so often. More frustrating is the fact that it seems to happen just as I am answering a question or voting on something, of course I do know that it is pure coincidence! :)

[image]
<sub>(source: [gibixonline.com](http://www.gibixonline.com/media/openid-activity.png))</sub>

I run the latest Chrome development version, currently 5.0.375.3, and have experienced this
through the last couple of versions (probably about 3 or 4 versions now) but it started on the same day as that previous question was asked. I do know that Chrome dev is not officially supported here, but seeing as how this issue is identical (in every way, except the fixed part) to the previously completed bug I wonder if they are related.

In reference to the [OpenID Troubleshooting Tips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/i-cant-log-in-with-my-openid-troubleshooting-tips):

1. At home yes, at work no. Another user on the same network and build of Chrome doesn't seem to
   have the issue.
2. <strike>No, I have not modified the cookie policy (other sites retain cookies just fine)</strike> - [Whoops! My bad - see my answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46677/keep-getting-logged-out-of-chrome-dev/46752#46752)
3. Yes, I've completely cleared my cookies, cache, saved passwords, etc.
4. Yes, I can stay logged in through IE.
5. Yes, they don't seem to have an issue. Though I do it mostly for commenting.
6. No, I confirmed that my profile information is valid.
7. It can be, but that's when I get the "No endpoint found" so this is a non-issue.
8. No, the initial site is in the clear and then gets redirected to MyOpenID.

Also of note: I set up the alternate provider (my parimary provider is my own site that directs to MyOpenID and my alternate is MyOpenID directly) as Google  and the issue still happened.

I am looking for confirmation that there is a bug here on SOFU or if I need to file a bug with Chrome. I currently use my same openid url for the SOFU sites as well as a couple others and I only experience the problem here. I know of other users using the same Chrome version without this issue (which worries me that it was something I did, but I cannot figure out what...). I do experience this on both my work machine and home so I do not think it is cache related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***sigh***

I feel like a complete idiot but I was able to fix the problem.

The fix?

Somehow (I am not sure how, but I probably did it) the option *Block all third-party cookies without exception* was checked. I had seen this checked before and discounted it because I didn't figure that the cookie to stay signed in was considered "third-party". I had ignored it because I did have cookies from stackoverflow.com/superuser.com/etc. and figured that was the authentication cookie.

Obviously not.

Unchecking the option has allowed me to log in to all 4 major sites and stay logged in.

Comment: May be SO could have a small check to see if this is the case and prompt the user in that case?

Comment: @json Once Jeff replies (and depending what the problem is), I think it should definitely be added to [OpenID Troubleshooting Tips](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/i-cant-log-in-with-my-openid-troubleshooting-tips)

Comment: well, good -- thanks for following up! And @jared this is already in the tips under "don't change default cookie policy"

Comment: Dang, I was hoping for another answer. :) I have Opera 10, cookies on, and in the past few weeks, have started getting logged out more often...

Answer (score 1):

We have seen LOTS of problems with development builds of Chrome.

We only officially support released versions of Chrome.

Comment: I am the "other user" he refers to - I use the same builds of Chrome dev on the same networks (we work at the same University, and both have Comcast HSI in the same city) and I don't have these problems. Do you have an "unoffical" idea to what the cause might be?

Comment: Yeah, I know, I've gotten that from you before. :) I guess I'm looking to see if it is still a bug on this end (since it did happen once for Chrome 4 and 5) or if I should file a bug report with Chrome. The biggest issue I have so far is, it only appears to happen with SOFU and no other sites.

Comment: @jared possibly bad plugins? Supporting dev builds is too expensive for the time it costs and the benefit is nil.

Comment: Jeff, I was able to fix it, but are the cookies considered third-party? I figured the authentication/information cookie stuff would be first-party since it originates from this site and all that fun stuff.