# I'm being logged out of SO every once in a while with FF 3.6.3

Tags: support, login, firefox, logout

I'm one of those who have a few SO pages open all day. I usually just hibernate my machine (I hardly ever reboot) and often hit the reload button for two pages (questions and responses) several times an hour.

Now, for the last one or two weeks (I think), I keep getting logged out of SO about once or twice a day while I reload. I hit the reload button (key, actually) for the two pages, and one of them indicates I'm out. If I then reload any of the other SO pages I have open, I'm out there, too. (I know that's, um, likely, but I had to say it anyway, right?) I hit the "login" link, Google logs me back in, and that's that.

I have no idea what makes these times different than the other times I reload. I haven't seen a correlation of this to anything. It just happens.

I do remember following Jeff's advice on how to create a Google profile so that transition between the sites gets better, but I cannot, for the live of me, remember whether I did this before or after this problem appeared for the first time.

FTR, I have seen [Keep getting logged out of Chrome dev](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46677/), [Keep getting logged out of StackOverflow today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44469/), and [I Can’t Log In With My OpenID — Troubleshooting Tips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/) and it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest switching web browsers and seeing if the condition persists. Or use Firefox "safe mode" which disables extensions.

As per usual with Firefox, I suspect add-ins interfering with cookies somehow.

Comment: Jeff, I watched this for a few days because of a suspicion I had. It seems this only happens when I reload several pages at the same time (hit reload, change tab, hit reload). At least, for two days it did never happened when I hit reload for one page only after the previous was done reloading. Using only the keyboard, I'm doing the reload fast enough that I reload two or three pages in probably a third of a second. So, considering network latency, from the server's POV they all arrive at the same time. Regarding that, can you think of something that could happen on server-side?

Comment: Jeff, consider this confirmed. I have trained myself now to not to reload more than one page at a time and I haven't had a logout in 24 hours. Of course, this could still be on my end. Yet, it seems suspicious.

Comment: I get this if I use "Reload All Tabs". I assumed it was a rate limiting feature if too many requests came in too close together.

Comment: This happens to me now as well but on Chrome 38.0. Haven't been able to figure out exactly when.