# Automatic logout when using Stack Overflow with Firefox

Tags: bug, status-norepro, logout

For the past 2-3 days, automatic logout is happening for my Stack Overflow account when using Firefox. It doesn't happen every time and looks to be random. I am using [MyOpenID](http://www.myopenid.com/) for authentication and have checked the option 'stay signed in' if it matters. Is this some sort of bug?

Comment: Happens to me too sporadically, also random intervals.

Comment: I've had that happen before, but it hasn't happened in a long time.

Comment: The Community user just bumped [a related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47726/im-being-logged-out-of-so-every-once-in-a-while-with-ff-3-6-3); @Naveen could this be what's happening to you?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect rogue add-ins in Firefox. No other reports of this, and we haven't experienced it on our fairly large (20+ people) team in daily use of all sites.

Try running in Firefox safe mode, or switch browsers for a few days.