# I've been logged out of the four sites, multiple times today, what's up?

Tags: support, logout

As per the title, I keep finding myself having been logged out of the sites.  As best as I can remember, once each on SU and Meta, twice each on SF and SO.  This [problem here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44469/keep-getting-logged-out-of-stackoverflow-today) was fixed, so I'm not sure if they're doing updates or there is some larger problem.

I use Google for OpenID, and Firefox 3.6 for the browser.

Edit: I just got another logout on SU, @12:43 pm.
Edit: SF, 1:23 pm.
Edit: Logged out one more time on SO & SU.  I've now done a complete restart and CCcleaned everything, so we'll see how  it goes.

Edit: After the cleanup, and giving it a day, no problem.  So just another unsolveable mystery bug.  I'll vote to close as no longer relevant.

Comment: I'm running the same configuration and haven't had a problem.

Comment: @Jon, thanks, maybe it's the ReloadEvery addon I use, though it's never happened like that before.

Comment: i had to login unexpectedly earlier on SU/SF/MSO but not on SO.  haven't noticed any further logouts.  also using FF3.6, not using Google for OpenID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you take the hint? We keep trying to get rid of you by logging you out, but you keep coming back!

(Yes, I'm kidding.)

Comment: +1 for my daily Meta laugh.