# Do the trilogy sites eventually log accounts off automatically?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, login, logout, 408-timeout

I'm wondering if I stay logged in without logging out or closing the browser if there is a timeout that will log me out from any of the trilogy sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearing the cookies on browser close will logout you from all sites (also the other sites which offers the same "remember me" functionality like Google/Gmail accounts). But when you're certain that this isn't caused by a client side cookie cleanup, then the only other cause may be that the server side has cleared all cookie keys from the datastore.

Answer (score 3):

As of logging in today, my cookie will expire in November. Therefore, there is an expiration date.

Comment: Which, if I am correct, will be postponed on every new session. At least, that's how the "remember me" cookie works on the average professional site.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what you mean by "stay logged in". If you just left your browser open for six months (I think) without ever clicking a link or refreshing the page, then you would be logged out because the session cookie would expire. The same holds true if you close your browser and don't visit the site for six months.

But for each trilogy site, as long as you're here at least once in any given six-month period (or however long the cookies are set to last), you shouldn't be logged out due to inactivity or any sort of time limit.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, there is no timeout that will log you out. However, from time to time, it has [been](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48175/ive-been-logged-out-of-the-four-sites-multiple-times-today-whats-up) [reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47726/im-being-logged-out-of-so-every-once-in-a-while-with-ff-3-6-3) to have happened in the past randomly.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to get logged out *relatively* frequently - a few times a week, maybe. Not a problem - I just click the Google button and I'm back in. I've wondered if this perhaps relates to my roaming - my laptop sees SOFU via my home broadband, my mobile broadband (on the train), and a corporate firewall.

But ultimately it has never irritated.

(except for an odd Chrome cookie bug in the past, but I think that is now fixed in Chrome)